# How do I bind a PrimeNG file upload component to my Angular form control?

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng, angular13, form-control

I'm using Angular 13 with PrimeNG.  I have this file upload component

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
...
    <p-fileUpload [customUpload]="true" (uploadHandler)="uploadFile($event)" [multiple]="false" formControlName="myFile"></p-fileUpload>
```

How do I bind this to my form's form control?  I have this in my service file

```
  form: FormGroup;
  ...
   this.form = this.fb.group({
    ...
    myFile: [null],
  });


    save(){
    ...
      const formData = new FormData();
      const myObject = this.form.value;
    ...
      console.log("file:" + myObject.myFile);
```

but even when I upload a file, I repeatedly see "file: null" output and no file is bound to my form control.  What's the proper way to bind my p-fileupload value to a form control?

Comment: I suspect you also have some errors related to value accessors in the console with this approach. I managed to have something working using a template driven approach. Check this stackblitz instance: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ng4zpr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I can get this path to work as well.  But I'd really like to know how to wire my form object to just automatically inherit the value of what is uploaded into that p-fileupload component, without my having to intervene.

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring because you have set the method save() to get the console.log. While you use `customUpload` and you want to get the file by clicking a button you can use `@ViewChild` method from angular. View the code and you will get to know how this works.

First give your `fileUpload` an id like `#fileUpload` and you don't need to set `formControlName` here. Instead you can set `new FormControl` in `formBuilder group`.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <p-fileUpload
    #fileUpload
    [customUpload]="true"
    (uploadHandler)="uploadFile($event)"
  ></p-fileUpload>
</form>
<button (click)="save()">save</button>
```

then in your `.ts` file you have to import `@ViewChild` method and view FileUpload.
And in `uploadFile` event we can get the file and using `patchValue` method we can set the value of the form field.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('fileUpload') fileUpload: FileUpload;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      myFile: new FormControl(),
    });
  }
  uploadFile(event) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
      this.form.patchValue({ myFile: file });
      this.form.get('myFile').updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  }
  save(){
    this.fileUpload.upload();
    console.log(this.form.value.myFile)
  }
}
```

**Demo** : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-fvsjxy?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for this creative solution although I have to ask -- why do we need to patch the value into the form ourselves?  Is it not possible to have the value automatically wired into the form like for a text field or a dropdown menu?

Comment: Yes of course you can. Is it a drop down menu you are selecting?

Comment: But why are you using `fileUpload` for a dropdown menu?

Comment: What I'm saying is when I add "formControl='name'" to a p-dropdown or input text, there are no additional steps required to bind to the form -- it just picks up the value based on what the user types in (or selects).  I'm curious why we have to add an additional step here to bind the file uploaded to the form and why doesn't it happen automatically.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it's because `File` is a type of object so we can't read it's properties directly like the other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `ControlValueAccessor` directive in order to automatically bind the uploaded file to a form control.
The template:

```html
<p-fileUpload formControlName="abcFile"></p-fileUpload>
```

The directive:

```
import { Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { FileUpload } from 'primeng/fileupload';

@Directive({
  selector: 'p-fileUpload[formControlName], p-fileUpload[formControl]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FileUploadControlValueAccessorDirective),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class FileUploadControlValueAccessorDirective
  implements ControlValueAccessor
{
  constructor(private fileUpload: FileUpload) {}

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    // update the model and changes logic goes here
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    // notify the outside world about changes (when the user interacts with the input)
    this.fileUpload.onUpload.subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    // here goes the touch logic
    this.fileUpload.onClear.subscribe(fn);
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this.fileUpload.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jhcz9a?file=src%2Fapp%2FFileUploadControlValueAccessor.directive.ts)

Comment: I think it does not work, controls are only accepted on input types. 
`core.mjs:8400 ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control unspecified name `

Comment: The Stackblitz works. DId you look at that?

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
...
    <p-fileUpload [customUpload]="true" name="file-upload" (uploadHandler)="uploadFile($event)" [multiple]="false" formControlName="myFile"></p-fileUpload>
```

and your form group should be

```
 form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  ...
   this.form = this.fb.group({
    ...
    myFile: new FormControl(''),
  });


    save(){
    ...
      const myObject = this.form.value;
    ...
      console.log("file:", myObject.myFile)  // do not use + operator, because it converts object to string as [Object Object] and it causes the confusion.
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.